# Restrict Firestore access to authenticated users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

What is the actual correct condition to use in the Firestore rules to restrict access to only authenticated users? The [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) and several answers here say that you should use `request.auth.uid != null`. I've used this in the past and it seemed to work, but recently when I was testing some other rules in the simulator I noticed that it throws a `Null value error` on that condition when the request is unauthenticated.

If that is the case, it seems that `request.auth != null` is the actual condition you should use, as it appears to behave as intended in the simulator.

Is this a discrepancy between the simulator and the actual behavior of the rules? If the simulator is correct, I assume the `request.auth.uid != null` condition only "works" because the default behavior is to deny access if there is an error in a condition. The other option is that the simulator is wrong and `request.auth` is never `null` when actually using the database.

Which is it?

Comment: Why do you say that the indicated question doesn't work in practice?

Comment: @AlexMamo I said that because it seemed to indicate that was the case and I hadn't had the change to fully test it myself. However, I've tested and it seems it does work and the documentation and majority of answers are actually wrong.

Comment: They have updated the documentation (at least the samples) to prefer request.auth != null.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did some testing with a few different conditions and found that my hypothesis appears to be correct -- the `request.auth.uid != null` condition is "working" because it throws an error when the user is unauthenticated. This probably doesn't cause any problems in most scenarios since you would likely want to deny access anyway; however, it does cause a problem if you try to write the inverse condition `request.auth.uid == null`. Since that throws an error when unauthenticated, it will also cause a rule to deny access.

My conclusion is that the docs are technically incorrect and the condition that should be used to check if the user is authenticated is `request.auth != null`. You can see the results of my tests below, with the incorrect behavior in bold.

### Tests

*Access restriction as described by the docs:*

```
allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid != null);
```

- Authenticated - access allowed
- Unauthenticated - access denied

*Alternate access restriction:*

```
allow read, write: if (request.auth != null);
```

- Authenticated - access allowed
- Unauthenticated - access denied

*Inverse restriction (docs condition):*

```
allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid == null);
```

- Authenticated - access denied
- **Unauthenticated - access denied**

*Inverse restriction (alternate condition):*

```
allow read, write: if (request.auth == null);
```

- Authenticated - access denied
- Unauthenticated - access allowed

Comment: Whenever accessing request.auth.uid for other purposes, I always apply it with a request.auth != null, it seems that it is more correct to respond with a denial than an error. return (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == {insert-condition-here})